# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR'

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I have the following jpeg as a bytecode string:

```
jpg = 'b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xfe\x00>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default quality\n\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x08\x06\x06\x07
```

I want to load this into OpenCV.

I tried:

```
import numpy as np

# CV2
nparr = np.fromstring(jpg , np.uint8)
img_np = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR )  # cv2.IMREAD_COLOR in OpenCV 3.1
```

I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR'
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 21):

You may try `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` if using OpenCv 3.1. It worked for me.